# Javascript изменить формат вывода времени в скрипте

Tags: javascript, jquery, скрипт, timezone, формат

Сразу оговорюсь что с JS я на Вы. На просторах интернета нашел вариант как изменять время (например комментария, или публикации статьи), согласно смещения времени пользователя, на его основе написал скрипт. Собственно сам скрипт:

```js
var date_with_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
$(".datetime-convert").each(function() {
  var offsetDate = new Date(parseDatetime($(this).text()).getTime() + -date_with_offset);
  $(this).text(offsetDate.toLocaleString());
});

function parseDatetime(value) {
  var a = /^(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/.exec(value);
  if (a) {
    return new Date(+a[3], +a[2] - 1, +a[1], +a[4], +a[5], +a[6]);
  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datetime-convert">24.02.2017 12:00:00</div>
```

Как Вы можете заметить дата выводится в формате: 24.02.2017 12:00:00.

Возможно ли вывести так: 24 февраля 2017 12:00:00.
И если да то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб изменить форматирование у даты, нужно указать доп. параметры для toLocaleString();
Ссылка на [учебник с датами](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime)

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.date-convert');
let elDate = el.textContent;
const timeOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

let brokenDate = elDate.split(' ')[0].split('.');
let time = elDate.split(' ')[1];

let fixedDate = `${brokenDate[1]}.${brokenDate[0]}.${brokenDate[2]} ${time}`;

let parsedDate = Date.parse(fixedDate) + -timeOffset;

const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  timezone: 'UTC',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric'
};

el.textContent = new Date(parsedDate).toLocaleString('ru', options)
```

```html
<div class="date-convert">24.02.2017 12:00:00</div>
```

Вот решение с jquery.

```js
$('.date-convert').each(function() {
 convertDate(this);
});


function convertDate(el) {
 let elDate = el.textContent;
  const timeOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

  let brokenDate = elDate.split(' ')[0].split('.');
  let time = elDate.split(' ')[1];

  let fixedDate = `${brokenDate[1]}.${brokenDate[0]}.${brokenDate[2]} ${time}`;

  let parsedDate = Date.parse(fixedDate) + -timeOffset;

  const options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };

  el.textContent = new Date(parsedDate).toLocaleString('ru', options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-convert">24.02.2017 12:00:00</div>
<div class="date-convert">24.02.2017 15:00:00</div>
```